# How to insert an alphabet/digit at specific location of string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am supposed to write a JavaScript function which inserts the character/s between only two consecutive Hash (`#`) symbols. For an example: If input string is:

```
var str = "#TIME##MONEY#";
```

Then output string must be `"#TIME#IS#MONEY#"`

Comment: Your efforts so far ? please post the code you have written so far as well

Comment: Must confess, I could not design any logic for this kind of operation.

Comment: There are lots of way to do it. one of them is using `replace` you can read about replace [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace() method.

```js
var str = "#TIME##MONEY#";
var insert = 'IS'

var newstr = str.replace('##', '#'+insert+'#')
console.log(newstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Splice the string where you find ## and concat the string

```js
var str = "#TIME##MONEY#";

for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == '#' && str[i + 1] == '#') {
    newStr = str.slice(0, i+1) + 'abc'
    +str.slice(i + 1, str.length);
  }
}
console.log(str)
console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: Thanks Syed Hassan, it worked. Meanwhile I also tried one more code, what is your opinion on this.                                                                                                   
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace(/##/, "#IS#");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

Comment: That's perfect I guess

Answer (score 0):

Just use replace

```js
// Once
var str = "#TIME##MONEY#";
document.write(str.replace('##','#IS#'));

//more than once
var str2 ="#TIME##MONEY##TIME##MONEY#";
while(str2.indexOf('##') != -1)
{
    str2 = str2.replace('##','#IS#');
}

document.write('<br />'+str2);
```

Comment: str.replace(/##/g,'#IS#') would also replace all